# AJAX service blocked by Google?

Tags: ios

I am working on an App to create pins on a world map for a group of customers. I was using google location service to get all the customer coordinates, you can see sample below:

```
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f,%.6f"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&rsz=8&sll=%@&q=%@", locationString, [cusName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

However I was using a program to do this for about 1000 customers and then I was blocked by google.

Then I realized this is not supposed to be allow by google:
https://developers.google.com/errors/
"We received automated requests, such as scraping and prefetching. Automated requests are prohibited; all requests must be made as a result of an end-user action"

It seems to me that I am blocked to make any more request, even for a single customer.

Does anyone know, what should I do to unblock me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Google mentions below on the page you linked how to get unblocked.

> In most cases, confirming compliance with the Terms of Use and performing the above steps will result in an automatic unblock within a short period of time. However, if your access to the API is not restored within a few hours of fixing the above problems, please contact us using the form below and we'll be glad to investigate further.

There is a form below on the page if you haven't been restored within a few hours. You may first want to check your application to see if it meets all the requirements outlined for the API.

Google recommends sending a userip parameter with the IP address of the user so it becomes less likely to appear as an automated bot (you can get the IP Address in Objective C using some low level networking code. See [Programmatically retrieving IP Address of iPhone](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone))